# How do I find a word in a file and insert text two lines below that?

Tags: linux, sed, find

I have a file that I want to find a key word in and enter text 2 lines down.

For example lets say the file i have contains the following words

```
the
cow
goes
moo
```

I want to be able to find the word "cow" and enter the text "yay" into the file 2 lines below the word cow.

```
the
cow
goes
moo
yay
```

I believe this would be done with `sed` but cannot get it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that none of the answers below will work as expected if `cow` occurs on more than one line and any two matching lines aren't separated by at least two non-matching lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
the
cow
goes
moo

$ sed '/cow/{N;N; s/$/\nyay/}' ip.txt 
the
cow
goes
moo
yay
```

- `N;N;` get next two lines
- `s/$/\nyay/` add another line

Comment: Thank Sundeep. I was able to use your provided command and add the -i to sed to accomplish what i need to do. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/cow/ {print; getline; print; getline; print; print "yay"; next}; 1'
```

- `/cow/` matches `cow` in the record, and then `{print; getline; print; getline; print; print "yay"; next}` prints the line, `getline` gets us the next line, that is printed too, same for the next, and then `yay` is printed, then goes to the next line (`next`)
- `1` (true) will print the rest of the lines as default action

Caveat:

- If there are less that two lines between the pattern to search and EOF, then the last line starting from pattern will be repeated to make two lines in between

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
the
cow
goes
moo

% awk '/cow/ {print; getline; print; getline; print; print "yay"; next}; 1' file.txt
the
cow
goes
moo
yay
```

Answer (score 0):

Other **sed**

```
sed '/cow/! b;n;n;a\yay' file.txt
```

Other **awk**

```
awk '{print;this--};/cow/{this=2}! this{print "yay"}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ed`

```
ed file << EOF
/cow/+2a
yay
.
,p
q
EOF
```

to print the modified output; or

```
ed file << EOF
/cow/+2a
yay
.
wq
EOF
```

or (as a `bash` one-liner)

```
printf '%b\n' '/cow/+2a' 'yay\n.' 'wq' | ed file
```

to write the changes in place.